Why am I Getting System.FormatException Error When Trying to Access MockService (SoapUI) Web Service?
I have a MockService (SoapUI) published on my local host. The URL that I get is the following: http://localhost:8088/mockCalculatorSoap.asmx?WSDL.
This was published using the public WSDL available here: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL. So basically I copied the content on a file and saved it with the WSDL extension on my disk. Then, using SoapUI, I opened this WSDL file and created a Mock Service for it. In the SoapUI tool, I can properly see all the methods available in this web service (add, divide, multiply and substract). To test this web service, I created a LabVIEW web service client. When I try to access the Add method, I get the following error:
**Error 1172 occurred at Invoke Node System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (5, 42).
Inner Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
Possible reason(s):
LabVIEW: (Hex 0x494) A .NET exception occurred in an external assembly. For information about correcting this error, copy the following exception (in bold), and search the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) Web site or the Web for a possible explanation.
System.FormatException in Calculator.lvlib:Add.vi->Test.vi**
Any ideas?
If I access the Web Service from the original URL http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL, everything works fine. So this is definitely related to the URL and how and where the Web Service is hosted.
